# Container alignment to the edge of browser window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a div that goes to the edge with the browser and would ilke to add content that is aligned to the centered container in the center of the page. I've crated a row with a col-md-6 that I filled with a background color but when I add the container, the content gets aligned to the edge of the browser not to the container's edge.

I am using Bootstrap and really need your help. If I did not articulate the issue properly, I've attached an image that should help.

Thanks for your help.

```css
.login-msg-box {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 margin-top: 200px;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 login-msg-box">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="msg-heading-line">LOG IN</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Image shows the current situation and the desired situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3htsD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you did a `margin-top` for the `.login-msg-box`, you could for example add a `margin-left` to your `.container`. Here's the result :

```css
.login-msg-box {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 margin-top: 200px;
 height: 400px;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 login-msg-box">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="msg-heading-line">LOG IN</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with that option is that I will lose the alignment with other elements on the page (e.g. logo) that are all aligned within the standard container. The problem with the preset margin is I can align it with a specific screen size but it would be misaligned with any other screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any number of offset to div

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 login-msg-box">
             <div class="container">
                  <h2 class="msg-heading-line">LOG IN</h2>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that would push the whole col to the other side of the screen not the container.

Comment: bootstrap container has fixed width. you can modify container width to achieve you desire result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/neya0v76/1/

I switch everything to `xs` so it looks right in the fiddle and just restructered your html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 login-msg-box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">

        <h2 class="msg-heading-line">LOG IN</h2>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```